# How does the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{h}$ induce a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{h}^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, bilinear-form, dual-spaces

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ a Cartan subalgebra. There is a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{h}$ which is a rescaling of the Killing form.

How does the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{h}$ induce a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{h}^*$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The form itself induces an isomorphism $\mathfrak h\to\mathfrak h^*$ given by mapping $x$ to the functional $\langle x,-\rangle$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, this has nothing to do with Lie algebras. If $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form on a finite-dimensional space $V$, it induces an isomorphism $\psi$ from $V$ onto its dual: $v\mapsto B(v,\cdot)$. So, you can define a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form on $V^*$:$$\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=B\bigl(\psi^{-1}(\alpha),\psi^{-1}(\beta)\bigr).$$